# Access NNTP group migrated to Google Groups with newsreader (NNTP)

Tags: google, google-groups, thunderbird

One of my favourite newsgroups (gmane.comp.lang.scala.user) recently moved to Google Groups. So I can't post messages from Thunderbird any more and I don't like the Google web interface.

Can I access the moved newsgroup in the same way I did before?

Comment: are you clear on the differences between e-mail and NNTP?  NNTP versus USENET? USENET uses the NNTP Protocol.  There are various clients for "news" or e-mail.  News clients use NNTP.  Pan is a news client, TBird is e-mail **and** a news client.  It depends on **adding** a **news server** to Tbird.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR It's impossible to use [NNTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) to access a group at Google Groups because this platform does not support this application protocol. Still, you might be able to continue using Thunderbird to read Google Group group posts.

---

Thunderbird is a desktop client for email messages and newsgroup posts. While Google Groups doesn't support the NNTP protocol, you can use Thunderbird to read the group messages if the group supports email subscriptions.

Regarding the specific example, as of October 18, 2023, the current group URL at Google Groups is https://groups.google.com/g/scala-user. From this URL, the group description says:

> ***[ARCHIVE ONLY] For new posts, visit https://users.scala-lang.org instead.***

Other Scala community resources are listed here.

Related

- [How is a Usenet group different from a normal group for ex - a Google Group?](https://superuser.com/q/43188)