# Does Google Groups provide NNTP access?

Tags: google-groups

Does Google/Google Groups have NNTP servers, to which one can connect and (possibly upon authentication) download previously-posted messages in a Google Group by group name?

---

Related question, but in a more limited context:

[Access Google Groups with newsreader (NNTP / Thunderbird)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12239/access-google-groups-with-newsreader-nntp-thunderbird)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Groups as platform doesn't support NNTP, it supports access through a web browser and email. The specific features available for each group depends on the group's owner/administrators.

Related

- [How to access Usenet postings from the earliest days of Usenet? (i.e. the 1980s)](https://superuser.com/q/733111/152004)